# How to localize the Authorization Right Description?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to set a right with a custom description. When calling `AuthorizationCopyRights()`, I expect to see my localized string but I see the key `kDescription`.  I can confirm that my application is correctly setup for localization by showing the localized string on the `NSTextField` in the window. I have seen [this technical documentation by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2095/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003110-CH1-SECTION7) but it seems like I am doing something incorrect? This is a sample code I have written in a Cocoa app to demonstrate it:

```
#define kRightName "TryingToLocalizePrompt"
- (IBAction) button : (id) sender
{
    AuthorizationRef authRef;
    OSStatus error = errAuthorizationSuccess;
    AuthorizationItem   oneRight = { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 };
    AuthorizationRights rights   = { 1, &oneRight };
    AuthorizationFlags flags    =   kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
        kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed    |
        kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize          |
        kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

    if (error == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
        error = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, &authRef);
    }

    if (error == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
        error = AuthorizationRightSet(
            authRef,
            kRightName,
            @kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsAdmin,
            (__bridge CFStringRef) @"kDescription", // <---- Not localizing?
            NULL, // I tried passing CFBundleGetMainBundle()
            NULL  // I have also tried (__bridge CFStringRef) @"Localizable"
        );
    }

    if (error == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
        oneRight.name = kRightName;
        error = AuthorizationCopyRights(
            authRef,
            &rights,
            NULL,
            kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed,
            NULL
        );
    }

    // Testing that localizable.strings file is correctly set into build:
    [self.label setStringValue: NSLocalizedString(@"kDescription", NULL)];

    error = AuthorizationRightRemove(authRef, kRightName);
}
```

This is my Localizable.strings file:

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings
  AuthRight

  Created by Brandon Fong on 6/19/21.
  
*/

"kDescription" = "Hello World!";
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon in the strings file?

Comment: My apologies, I spotted the typo before posting this but did not make the change to the post.  I made the edits to my post.